# How to do Yeo Johnson feature normalization on test data?

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, normalization

I have  a training and test data as part of cross validation. As I normalize training data using
Yeo Johnson transform, to prevent data leakage, I plan to save the lambada from training data normalization, and use it for test data normalization.
I wrote small snippet to test this as below:

```
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), dpi=600)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(421)
xTr = stats.loggamma.rvs(5, size=500) + 5
prob = stats.probplot(xTr, dist=stats.norm, plot=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_title('Probplot:Train')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(422)
sns.distplot(xTr, color="skyblue")
ax2.set_title('Distribution of Training Data')

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(423)
xt_scipy, lmbda = stats.yeojohnson(xTr)
prob = stats.probplot(xt_scipy, dist=stats.norm, plot=ax3)
ax3.set_title('Probplot:Yeo-Johnson:Scipy on train')

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(424)
sns.distplot(xt_scipy, color="skyblue")
ax4.set_title('Distribution of Transformed Train Data')

ax5 = fig.add_subplot(425)
xTst = stats.loggamma.rvs(10, size=500) + 5
# xTst = stats.loglaplace.rvs(7, size=500)
prob = stats.probplot(xTst, dist=stats.norm, plot=ax5)
ax5.set_xlabel('')
ax5.set_title('Probplot:Test')

ax6 = fig.add_subplot(426)
sns.distplot(xTst, color="skyblue")
ax6.set_title('Distribution of Test Data')

ax7 = fig.add_subplot(427)
xtst_scipy = stats.yeojohnson(xTst, lmbda=lmbda)
prob = stats.probplot(xtst_scipy, dist=stats.norm, plot=ax7)
ax7.set_title('Probplot:Yeo-Johnson:Scipy on Test')

ax8 = fig.add_subplot(428)
sns.distplot(xtst_scipy, color="skyblue")
ax8.set_title('Distribution of Transformed Test Data')
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0.9, w_pad=0.9)
plt.show()
```

This gives following plots.
[image: Fig1]
I have following questions:

1. Is normalization step for test data done correctly using Scipy as shown in my code ?
2. How can this be done in SKlearn , using previously computed lambda from training data? The reason I ask is that Sklearn *PowerTransformer* and *fit_transform* for Yeo Johnson does not allow passing precomputed lambda.

Thank You
sedy

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are misunderstanding Transformers function. `fit_transform()` is performed on the train set and compute the lambda and scaling function. Once they are computed, you can use the `transform()` function to apply this transformation on the test set.

Concerning your first question, it is wise to use scikit-learn transformer instead of scipy transformation as they are standard and can be added to a pipeline.

For the second question, you can use `PowerTransformer` without fitting it by setting the lambdas manually as follows:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer

pt = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson', standardize=False)
pt.lambdas_=[1,2]
pt.transform([[10,20]])
```